# Flutter Navigator.popUntil failed assertion _debugLocked. What's wrong?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

^ ^ ^^ ^ NO!  THIS QUESTION DOES **NOT** HAVE AN ANSWER THERE! ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^

I'm having problems with `Navigator.popUntil`. I wrote a small demo app to show what's happening. Before I post this as a bug, am I using `popUntil` wrong??

call to popUntil displays

[image]

It looks like something is locking up the Navigator (setting `_debugLocked`) and not releasing it.

main.dart below : (can just be pasted into the Flutter demo app)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Routing Test Page'),
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/':
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => MyHomePage(title: 'Home Page',),
              settings: settings,
            );
          case '/home':
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => MyHomePage(title: 'Home Page',),
              settings: settings,
            );
          case '/middlepage':
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => MiddlePage(),
              settings: settings,
            );
          case '/bottompage':
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => BottomBage(),
              settings: settings,
            );
          default:
            return null;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Home Page',
            ),
            OutlineButton(
              child: Text('push MiddlePage()'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => (MiddlePage())),
              ),
            ),
            OutlineButton(
              child: Text('pushNamed ''/middlepage'''),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/middlepage'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MiddlePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Middle Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Middle Page',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
            ),
            OutlineButton(
              child: Text('push BottomPage()'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => (BottomBage())),
              ),
            ),
            OutlineButton(
              child: Text('pushNamed ''/bottompage'''),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/bottompage'),
            ),
            OutlineButton(
                child: Text('pop'), onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
            OutlineButton(
                child: Text('popUntil ''/home'''),
                onPressed: () =>
                    Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/home'))),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomBage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bottom page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Bottom Page', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            OutlineButton(
              child: Text('push ''home'''),
              onPressed: () =>
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home'),
            ),
            OutlineButton(
                child: Text('pop'),
                onPressed: () =>
                    Navigator.pop(context)),

            OutlineButton(
              child: Text('popUntil ''/home'''),
              onPressed: () =>
                  Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/home')),
            ),
            OutlineButton(
              child: Text('popUntil ''/home'' (with Are You Sure box)) '),
              onPressed: () async {
                try {
                  if (await _areYouSureDialog(context)) {
                    Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/home'));
                  }
                } catch (e) {
                  debugPrint("exception: $e");
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<bool> _areYouSureDialog(BuildContext context) async {
  return await showDialog<bool>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Pop back?'),
            content: const Text('Are you sure?'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: const Text('YES'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: const Text('NO'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ) ??
      false;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error thrown on navigator pop until : "!\_debugLocked': is not true."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618717/error-thrown-on-navigator-pop-until-debuglocked-is-not-true)

Comment: @Nuts Its a similar error, but in that question, the asker is nesting calls to push/pop. In this case it's a simple navigation - push down one level, then push to the next level. Then when popUntil to get to the top....BANG. (it even crashes when just going down one level)
So it's similar, but it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recreated your case. Whenever we want to pop navigation to the home screen (root) from anywhere, there are couple of ways to do it as below:

1.Using `.isFirst` method:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
```

2. Using `defaultRouteName`:

`Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(Navigator.defaultRouteName));`

By providing the `context` first, the `route` will ensure that the navigation will pop to the default always.

You can try with either approach. I tested at my end and it works well.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had tried `defaultRouteName` already (or so I though) and it had failed. `defaultRouteName` always seems to return as "\" (which is why I had added the otherwise unused "\" to the routing table. trying it again seems to work so thanks. The other option `route.isFirst` I kinda like better. 
I still think I need to report this as a bug. My expectation (from the documentation) is that `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/home'))` should work. Either way, the assert error isn't helpful.