# Failed assertion: !_debugLocked is not true when using Navigator.popUntil() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-widget

In my flutter app I use this code to go to my dashboard page, but it fails to do so the first time and I get the `debugLocked` error.

The launch page in the app is a Router that checks for shared preferences "sessionid" which, if set, takes the user directly to the Dashboard, else takes them to the login.

Without the below code, I get to my Dashboard just fine, using `Navigator.pushReplacement()` but then, a back arrow appears on the appBar. This back button takes the app back to the Router.

I searched for answers on how to remove all screens from the navigator and the following was what I found.

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName(Dashboard.id));
```

Using the above code gives me the `debugLocked` error. Is there a solution to mitigate this problem?  Or is there any other efficient way for me to remove screens from the context? Does setting `automaticallyImplyLeading` to `false` help somehow? Because this error only occurs after someone has logged in or signed up.

Comment: Do you want to navigate to a directly previous page? if that is the case you only need to use: Navigator.pop(context);

Comment: Also, you can change your navigation and use the Pages references instead of Routes and I think is a better way to navigate on Flutter

Comment: No, I don't want to navigate to a previous page. Secondly, could you please elaborate what do you mean by using pages reference? And how is it better than routes?

Comment: You can navigate with references to a Pages like:  Navigator.push(HomePage()) and for me is better because you don't need to create a route for each page and is easier to pass parameters to the different Pages, that's my preference and I think is the recommended way to navigate in Flutter

Comment: That I do know about, I was not uptodate with the terminology. However, that shill doesn't answer my question.

Comment: This helped me alot, hope it helps others too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65699320/10288513

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to remove all the previous routes use [`Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html)

Comment: I'll try this and let you know!

Comment: Yes, that solved the issue. If I may be excused..can you please explain why the `popUntil` method failed here? Or why `pushAndRemoveUntil` is better than the former?

Comment: PushAndRemoveUntil is no better than PushReplacement. I could explain the difference that is actually quite trivial. PushReplacement replaces the current navigator path by pushing the specified path and then deleting the previous path, instead PushAndRemoveUntil deletes all previous routes. Unfortunately I can't explain to you why popUntil doesn't work unless I see your code

Answer (score 1):

This can be another alternative, if you for some reason face a setState error.

```
navigationService.popUntil((_) => true);
navigationService.navigateTo(
  'authentication',
);
```

basically i wait until the navigation finish setting everything and then call the navigateTo.