# how to fix !_debuglocked error in newly created project in flutter?

Tags: flutter

can someone help me out please, i couldnt solve this problem, some say this is the the navigation error, some say do flutter clean and flutter doctor etc, but it didnt work,
this is just a simple statelesswidget that was supposed to go to the otherscreen after clicking either two buttons, and nothing much information other than that,,

please check my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:survey/content/agreement.dart';
import 'package:survey/widgets/animations.dart';
import 'package:survey/widgets/widgetlist.dart';
import '../widgets/buttonstyle.dart';

class choosepage  extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    precacheImage(AssetImage(imgtit), context);
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Welcome to",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.indigo,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                      SizedBox(width: 15),
                      Image.asset(imgtit,width: 200,height: 100,),
                      SizedBox(height: 40),
                      Image.asset(imgtit2,width: 250,height: 150,),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 70,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Select Language',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.indigo,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Pumili ng Wika',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.indigo,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                ),
                roundedRectButton("English", signInGradients,Navigator.push(context, SlideRightRoute(page: agreementscreen()));),
                roundedRectButton("Tagalog", signUpGradients,Navigator.push(context, SlideRightRoute(page: agreementscreen()));)
              ],
            )
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Here is where it comes from

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Contents/choosepage.dart';
import 'Contents/welcomebox.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.indigoAccent,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: choosepage(),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the error please help me!

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here are the animations for route that i use, which includes the sliderightroute,
feel free to check

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class ScaleRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;
  ScaleRoute({this.page})
      : super(
    pageBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        ) =>
    page,
    transitionsBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        Widget child,
        ) =>
        ScaleTransition(
          scale: Tween<double>(
            begin: 0.0,
            end: 1.0,
          ).animate(
            CurvedAnimation(
              parent: animation,
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            ),
          ),
          child: child,
        ),
  );
}

class SlideRightRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;
  SlideRightRoute({this.page})
      : super(
    pageBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        ) =>
    page,
    transitionsBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        Widget child,
        ) =>
        SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(
            begin: const Offset(1, 0),
            end: Offset.zero,
          ).animate(animation),
          child: child,
        ),
  );
}

class FadeRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;
  FadeRoute({this.page})
      : super(
    pageBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        ) =>
    page,
    transitionsBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        Widget child,
        ) =>
        FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation,
          child: child,
        ),
  );
}

class SizeRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;
  SizeRoute({this.page})
      : super(
    pageBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        ) =>
    page,
    transitionsBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        Widget child,
        ) =>
        Align(
          child: SizeTransition(
            sizeFactor: animation,
            child: child,
          ),
        ),
  );
}
```

**Here is the RoundedRectButton**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget roundedRectButton(String title, List<Color> gradient,loc) {
  return Builder(builder: (BuildContext mContext) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment(1.0, 0.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              loc;

            },
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 60,
              width: MediaQuery.of(mContext).size.width / 1.3,
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: gradient,
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight),
              ),
              child: Text(title,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(

                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),maxLines: 1,),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  });
}

const List<Color> signInGradients = [
  Color(0xFF0EDED2),
  Color(0xFF32127a),
];

const List<Color> signUpGradients = [
  Color(0xFF87e650),
  Color(0xFF3a8c0b),

];


class CustomClipPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  var radius=8.0;
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(radius, 0.0);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(0.0, radius),
        clockwise: true, radius: Radius.circular(radius));
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - radius);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(radius, size.height),
        clockwise: true, radius: Radius.circular(radius));
    path.lineTo(size.width - radius, size.height);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width, size.height - radius),
        clockwise: true, radius: Radius.circular(radius));
    path.lineTo(size.width, radius);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width - radius, 0.0),
        clockwise: true, radius: Radius.circular(radius));
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: please post the roundedRectButton code

Comment: Though, the problem is either the route not returning a widget that has a build widget or the SlidingRightRoute class. Either way, the first time I read the code might be he bypass the linter(Pascal Case). 
It's a duplicate for this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618717/error-thrown-on-navigator-pop-until-debuglocked-is-not-true

Comment: updated the code with the slider animation and the roundedrectbutton and its parameter

Comment: @Clueless i couldnt understand his solution so thats why i posted this here,

Comment: can i follow this up? same issue still after reinstalling and reformating my pc