# Flutter | NoSuchMethodError: The method 'round' was called on null. E/flutter (25849): Receiver: null

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Constantly getting this error since i override the ErrorWidget.builder in the main function. I only see the exception i navigate to a specific widget(Not initially. I be on the page for few minutes, this starts getting printed automatically in console gradually & keeps printing. Once this error appears on console, i see this error every time i tap on something. `package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 1748 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.` ) . The problem i face is , i don't know where to lookup for the reason..came up all in sudden today & i have no clue to debug. Has anybody else seen this error before ??

```
E/flutter (25849): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'round' was called on null.
E/flutter (25849): Receiver: null
E/flutter (25849): Tried calling: round()
E/flutter (25849): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (25849): #1      PageController.nextPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:227:31)
E/flutter (25849): #2      _CarouselSliderState.getTimer.<anonymous closure> (package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart:172:14)
E/flutter (25849): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter (25849): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter (25849): #5      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:987:7)
E/flutter (25849): #6      _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1024:26)
E/flutter (25849): #7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1196:13)
E/flutter (25849): #8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter (25849): #9      _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1008:26)
E/flutter (25849): #10     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter (25849): #11     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter (25849): #12     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
E/flutter (25849):
```

Comment: did you use any `round()` method?

Comment: No, i dug my code for any such usage & i clearly don't see that method anywhere..

Comment: show me the code

Comment: @AmonChowdhury : Like i said, that's the problem. Not sure which code is throwing the exception.

Comment: Here you have very detailed answer about the role of `_debugLocked`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55622474/5700535

Also, you can check this out: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36177

Comment: How have you initialized `CarouselSlider` (place code in the question) ? Seems there's an issue with `page` index being null, a hunch.

Comment: Arvind, thank you for the response man.. I believe i got it right somehow...dont remember how.. been sometime... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

if you use carousel_pro. it's from the plugin src.
try update

```
if ((_controller.page!=null) && (_controller.page.round() == widget.images.length - 1)) {
```

I already create pull request to the source. hope it will be updated.

cheers