# Close loading dialog in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using Futurebuilder in flutter and having issue while closing the showDialog

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
return Scaffold(
    appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size( 50.0),            
    body: FutureBuilder(
        future: widget.getAutoCompleteData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {         

           Navigator.of(context).pop();

          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          } else {
             LoadingDialog.showLoadingDialog(context, _scaffoldKey);
          }
          return Center(
            child: Container(child: Text("sds"),),
          );
        }));
```

}

Getting below error when screen loads

```
package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5013 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: widget.getAutoCompleteData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {         

           Navigator.of(context).pop();

          } else if (snapshot.hasError) { //here this is empty
          } else {//remove else statement
             LoadingDialog.showLoadingDialog(context, _scaffoldKey);
          }
          return Center(
            child: Container(child: Text("sds"),),
          );
        })
```

To This

```
FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
      future: _dataFetcher.getPosts(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return LoadingDialog.showLoadingDialog(context, _scaffoldKey);
        }
        return Center(child: Text('${snapshot.data![0].title}'));
      },
    )
```

Comment: Instead of CircularProgressIndicator i would like to show the custom loading dialog. which I have used acrossed the app

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the **re-entrant** of the Navigator (you can check the answer here: [Error thrown on navigator pop until : “!_debugLocked': is not true.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618717/error-thrown-on-navigator-pop-until-debuglocked-is-not-true)

)

Or, maybe you don't want to use `FutureBuilder`. The FutureBuilder is meant to **stay in the same widget/page** and show different screens when future data is not ready. If you want to push a loading dialog and close it when data is ready, you can just simply use a Future function

```
Future pressTheButton(context) async {
  LoadingDialog.showLoadingDialog(context, _scaffoldKey); // showDialog here
  final data = await getAutoCompleteData();  // await the data
  Navigator.of(context).pop();  // pop the loading dialog

  // return your data or error
  // or rebuild the current widget with the data
}
```