# In ListTile, onTap not working, shows Failed Assertion

Tags: flutter

Here is the code

```
ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                    title: Text(
                      ("My Account"),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(profilePage);
                    },
                  ),
```

Here is route file

```
const String loginPage = 'loginScreen';
const String homePage = 'main';
const String profilePage = 'profileScreen';

Route<dynamic> controller(RouteSettings settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    case loginPage:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen());
    case homePage:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => App());
    case profilePage:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Profile());
    default:
      throw ('This route does not exist');
  }
```

here is the error:

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4134 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
═══════════════════════════════════════════

Comment: I am sure that you have more error message but check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618717/error-thrown-on-navigator-pop-until-debuglocked-is-not-true

Comment: can you provide your main.dart code?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1amToHXHV_UnhT_rHBMp1WJVauBJxOxjnQr3LUxiTogg/edit?usp=sharing

I have pasted "main.dart" in the word file. Please review it.

Answer (score 0):

try below code hope it help to you refer official documentation for Navigator.pushNamed [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamed.html)

```
case loginPage:  (context)=>LoginScreen(),
```

and inside ListTile

```
 onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context,profilePage);
            },
```