# Error occured when created a navigation in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Assertion failed:
..\…\widgets\navigator.dart:4595
!_debugLocked
is not true

code

```dart
void checkLogin(BuildContext ctx) {
    final _username = _usernameController.text;
    final _password = _passwordController.text;
    if (_username == _password) {
      print('username and password  match');
      //GoTo Home
      Navigator.of(ctx).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx1) => ScreenHome()),
      );
    } else {
      print('username and password doesnot match');
    }
  }
```

Error Image
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSX73.png)

Comment: Please attach your code sample and image of the error for clarification.

Comment: @K_Chandio Added code and image

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618717/error-thrown-on-navigator-pop-until-debuglocked-is-not-true) will help you alot. try the solutions provided by the expert and I hope your issue will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

i think u missed to provide context to push()

```
Navigator.push(
      ctx,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx) => ScreenHome(),
      ),
    );
```