# Error: Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2845 pos 18: '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

I face a problem about `Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2845 pos 18: '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true`.

This is my Debug Console:

```
E/flutter ( 5236): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2845 pos 18: '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true.
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2845
E/flutter ( 5236): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
E/flutter ( 5236): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
E/flutter ( 5236): #2      _RouteEntry.handlePush.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2845
E/flutter ( 5236): #3      TickerFuture.whenCompleteOrCancel.thunk
package:flutter/…/scheduler/ticker.dart:407
E/flutter ( 5236): #4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
E/flutter ( 5236): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter ( 5236): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5236): #6      TickerFuture.whenCompleteOrCancel.thunk
package:flutter/…/scheduler/ticker.dart:406
E/flutter ( 5236): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5236):
```

Here is some code:

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618717/error-thrown-on-navigator-pop-until-debuglocked-is-not-true

Comment: I've looked at the answers at that link and none of those answers worked for me.

Comment: I don't understand what "r u use Navigator.push() remove that" means.

Comment: are You use Navigator.push() so  remove that

Comment: No, I am using Navigator.pop(context).

Comment: Ok flutter doctor -v run this command and share coomand line code

Comment: Hi can u share your anydesk id to solve ur issue

Comment: It's better if you share a piece of code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this should solve.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyPage()));
});
```

extracted from [Error thrown on navigator pop until : "!_debugLocked': is not true."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618717/error-thrown-on-navigator-pop-until-debuglocked-is-not-true)

Answer (score -2):

One of the way to solve this error is

Setting `(Route<dynamic> route) => false` will make sure that all routes before the pushed route are removed. This removes all routes in the stack so that user cannot go back to the previous routes after they have logged out.

if this does not work than you are on obsolete version of the framework. Current stable is `2.10.1`. I recommend  you to upgrade to latest which should resolve your issue.

Answer (score -3):

- Replace `Navigator.pop(context)` with `Navigator.of(context).pop(context)`
- And Restart your application.