# debugLocked is not true in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing error in my Flutter project when I do hot reload, this error (below) comes. In hot restart, it works fine. I have to find this error solution as soon as possible.

I am getting error in in Flutter code:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2928 pos 18: '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true.
```

This is the error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating *after* the widget (probably a "screen") has already been built:

Something like this:

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyPage()));
});
```

Without seeing your code it's hard to give a tailored solution.

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71274632/13029516