# '!_debugLocked': is not true

Tags: flutter, debugging, flutter-dependencies, dart-async

Function:

```
    navigateToAudioScreen(file, aPlay) async {
//    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
      Navigator.pop(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
         return AudioPlayerScreen(
          a_play: aPlay,
          a_file: file,
        );
      }));
    }
    );
  }
```

Error:

```
flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigato
r.dart': Failed assertion: line 4842 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
E/flutter (11069): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:47:61)
E/flutter (11069): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
E/flutter (11069): #2      NavigatorState.pop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4842:12)
E/flutter (11069): #3      Navigator.pop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2432:27)
E/flutter (11069): #4      _HomePageState.navigateToAudioScreen.<anonymous closure> (/Screens/Home.dart:95
:17)
```

Attempts:

1. Tried adding Scheduler Bind
2. Tried adding Widget Bind
3. Tried adding Future Delay

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error thrown on navigator pop until : "!\_debugLocked': is not true."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618717/error-thrown-on-navigator-pop-until-debuglocked-is-not-true)

Comment: I tried those those, it didn't work out, even tried pushandreplace too !!

Comment: Can you provide simplify version of it, you can check [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

This error might be because `Navigator.pop()` method does not take MaterialPageRoute as a parameter and hence it is throwing this error.
You can check more on this at: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html