# no error but navigator with the drawer does not work flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

after many trier navigator does not work well sometimes it is work but navigate wrong page

this error appears when taping drawer widget

[image]

Comment: Share your code segment of Drawer Widget

Comment: It means that there is a re-entrant call to push, pop, and friends. If you provide code more may be said. Check explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618717/error-thrown-on-navigator-pop-until-debuglocked-is-not-true

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error thrown on navigator pop until : "!\_debugLocked': is not true."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618717/error-thrown-on-navigator-pop-until-debuglocked-is-not-true)

Comment: The above comments might solve your issue, and It would be better if you could provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

For your **!_debugLocked is not true** problem,

You may add delayed for next page go through .

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
  Navigator.of(context)
      .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
  WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(context);
});
```